# Delay in the kernel driver

Tags: windows, kernel, cpu-usage, windows-kernel

I'm using while loop in the kernel driver for read memory, but I get high cpu usage.

In C# there is `Sleep();` which reduces cpu usage in the while loop.
What can I use in the kernel driver on Windows?

Comment: Please, add the tag describing **Operating System** which kernel you are programming for. Different OS have different API when program kernel.

Comment: Check last word, i say that on Windows

Comment: KeDelayExecutionThread

Answer (score 0):

When shared memory or data is ready in your kernel driver .
You can create events to notify user-mode applications of this.

```
#define GT_GLOBAL_EVENTNAME L"\\BaseNamedObjects\\KernelEvent_6BAC23F4"
PKEVENT     g_UserModeEvent = NULL; 
HANDLE      g_hEvtHandle = NULL; 

UNICODE_STRING evtName;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&evtName, GT_GLOBAL_EVENTNAME);

g_UserModeEvent = IoCreateNotificationEvent(&evtName, &g_hEvtHandle);
if (g_UserModeEvent == NULL ||
    g_hEvtHandle== NULL)
{
    rtStatus = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    goto CleanUp;
}
KeResetEvent(g_UserModeEvent );
```

When the data is ready, notify the application using the code below.

```
KeSetEvent(g_UserModeEvent , 0, FALSE);                KeResetEvent(g_UserModeEvent );
```

The application can obtain a handle of the event created by the kernel driver using OpenEvent and wait in WaitForSingleObject through the handle.

```
HANDLE m_hEvent = NULL;
WCHAR tmpEvtName[1024] = { L"\\BaseNamedObjects\\KernelEvent_6BAC23F4" };
m_hEvent = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, tmpEvtName);
WaitForSingleObject(m_hEvent, INFINITE);
```

After that, the application can read the shared memory or request data from the kernel driver using DeviceIoControl.